# PostGIS, Generating a city "code" for every city on earth

Tags: postgis

I'd like to be able to query a PostGIS table with a lnglat and have it return a four letter.

The point [180, 90] should return AAAA, and the point [-180, -90] should return ZZZZ.

Kind of like this: https://map.what3words.com/soon.escalator.minimalists

Maybe this is just a simple fishnet grid? Is that the right way to make this?

I would like the grid to be accurate to the tenths or hundredths column of latitude. It doesn't have to be a square grid.

Cities can have multiple codes but each city should have a unique code.

edit: I realize that 26^4 might not be enough to cover the whole earth with the accuracy that I desire. So I'm thinking since most of the earth is water we could do something like this:

http://blog.cleverelephant.ca/2018/06/polygon-splitting.html

maybe this isn't possible with four letters, but six letters it should be doable if we ignore ocean (361800000 sqkm / 26 / 26 / 26 / 26 / 26 / 26) right?

Comment: Why not use the IATA Codes? https://www.nationsonline.org/oneworld/IATA_Codes/airport_code_list.htm

Comment: not every city has an airport. that's the main reason. I'm actually using IATA as a key for airport cities, my use case of this four letter identifier is specifically for rural cities.

Comment: Have you considered [plus codes](https://plus.codes/developers)?

Comment: ah. I've seen plus codes before but I didn't like how long they were. I didn't realize you can shorten them to just 6 or 8 characters so this is acceptable. I think I'll just use plus codes then :)

Comment: How about geohashing, just to add my $0.02, https://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeoHash.html. Then, there is https://what3words.com/. So, there probably is no correct way of doing this, but, the the techniques of spatial partioning, with longer and longer strings for greater degrees of accuracy, are well understood.

Comment: That's pretty neat! I didn't realize PostGIS had this functionality built-in. I probably would've just used that had I known about it prior. Plus codes were also easy to implement. It only took about 5mins